# Differences in async-await execution flows

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

What's the difference between a top-down flow (where top is an API action and down is a Db transaction) using the following two approaches.

A full async-await flow

```
async Task X()
{
   await Y();
}

async Task Y()
{
    await Z();
}

async Task Z()
{
    await session.CommitAsync();
}
```

Only the top-level method uses async-await.

```
async Task X()
{
   await Y();
}

Task Y()
{
    Z();

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

Task Z()
{
    session.CommitAsync();

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

while the async instructs that Y should be executed async, what happens to Z ?

Comment: async/await is a compiler feature that let's you avoid callbacks/lambdas, are you asking about programming convenience or performance?

Comment: It really depends on what `something` does. If it does not use real asynchronicity, there is no real difference.

Comment: Did you mean to call `something` in the second snippet? If not, the two bits of code are completely different anyway. Also, what is `_Z`, another mistake?

Comment: The last method still doesn't do anything, were you meant to do `return something();`?

Comment: Your latest edit will give you compiler warnings because you don't await the call to `CommitAsync`

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: the question changed. General async answer below*

The following `Z` will simply not wait for `CommitAsync` before returning. It's a fire and forget situation.

```
Task Z()
{
    session.CommitAsync();

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

In an api controller situation this means that the web request would return to client before the session is committed.

Let's note this cannot be done for methods that return data.

The 2nd note is that there is no benefit here from returning a `Task`, and the return type could be changed to `void` (which may or may not help you reason about it).

*Origjnal answer, still relevant*

Let's say that in `ZRealAsync` calls `await db.(...).ToListAsync()` and `ZPretendAsync` calls `ToList()` and then returns `Task.CompletedTask`.

The difference is that a thread that happens to call `ZRealAsync` can be used to do other things after the query is sent to the database, and a thread which calls `ZPretendAsync` will not be able to be used for anything else until the result is obtained from the database, it will just wait; even if `X` is marked `async` and uses `await`.

If your web controllers call `ZPretendAsync` then the system won't be able to handle more concurrent requests than there are threads available, even if `X` is marked `async` and uses the `await` keyword. With `ZRealAsync` n threads can service more than n concurrent requests. `Async` makes a real difference, but only if it's real.

Comment: Yes. Your example has changed so the dynamics are different (the current code in the question is a fire-and-forget case)